# Sorting list of dictionaries according to a certain key

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary

```
    runnerList = [{1:{"name":"John","height":173,"age":16}},
                  {2:{"name":"Fred","height":185,"age":18}},
                  {3:{"name":"Luke","height":181,"age":17}}]
```

I've been trying to sort this list of dictionaries in ascending order according to the age of the runners, with no success :( I tried:

```
    import operator
    runnerList.sort(key=lambda x: x['age'], reverse=True)
```

But nothing seemed to happen. How would i do this?

Comment: because you have a dictionary inside another dictionary.

Comment: You should get a `KeyError` for this, hard to believe that nothing happened.

Comment: Is there some reason you're using a list of single-element ascending-integer-keyed dictionary-containing dictionaries? It's a rather peculiar data structure.

Comment: Unless you have some external constraint you haven't mentioned, a simple list of dictionaries like `[{"name": "John", "height": 173, "age": 16}, {"name": "Fred", "height": 185, "age": 18}, {"name": "Luke", "height": 181, "age": 17}]` would be a lot easier to deal with.

Comment: To convert to the data model proposed by @ZeroPiraeus `[next(iter(x.values())) for x in runnerList]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
runnerList.sort(key=lambda x: x.values()[0]['age'])
print runnerList
```

The reason you were getting an error is that your relevant dictionaries (those containing the `age` key) were also contained inside another dictionary. The solution was just as simple getting the `values()` of that external `dict` and getting grabbing the first element (`[0]`) which gave you the only dictionary contained inside.

Also, I removed the `reverse=True` used in your example. It would have given you the results in descending order and you specifically asked for them to be in *ascending order*.

#### Disclaimer:

If you're using a Python version >= 3:, you'd have to convert the generator object created with `values()`.

```
runnerList.sort(key=lambda x: list(x.values())[0]['age'])
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj Not here... Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

`runnerList` is list of dictionaries of dictionaries.
if you are sure that each list entry has only one pair of key-value, then you can sort by:

```
runnerList.sort(key=lambda x: list(x.values())[0]['age'], reverse=True)
```

if each list entry has more then one key-value pair, then you need to specify better the logic of your sort. what would you do on list like this?:

```
runnerList = [{1:{"name":"John","height":173,"age":16}},
                  {  2:{"name":"Fred","height":185,"age":18},
                     4:{"name":"Fred","height":185,"age":13}
                  },
                  {3:{"name":"Luke","height":181,"age":17}}]
```

Comment: `TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing`

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus your error occur only on python 3. I ran it on 2.7. anyway, the answer to the question is still the same, the problem is that it is dict of dicts.

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:python-3.x].

Comment: you can do `runnerList.sort(key=lambda x: list(x.values())[0]['age'], reverse=True)` in python 3. i'll fix my answer to work on 3 too. tnx

Answer (score -1):

You basically have the runnerList in form of list as it is enclosed in `[]`. First change it to dictionary like

```
 runnerList = {1:{"name":"John","height":173,"age":16},
              2:{"name":"Fred","height":185,"age":18},
              3:{"name":"Luke","height":181,"age":17} }
```

and then you can `import operator` and can use the below function to sort the items and print it

```
sorted_runnerList = sorted(runnerList.items(),key=lambda x: x[1]['age'],)
```

While this would directly sort the age in the dictionary within the dictionary

So basically your function becomes

```
import operator
runnerList = {1:{"name":"John","height":173,"age":16},
              2:{"name":"Fred","height":185,"age":18},
              3:{"name":"Luke","height":181,"age":17} }

sorted_runnerList = sorted(runnerList.items(),key=lambda x: x[1]['age'],)
print sorted_runnerList
```

**But do remember as we are using the .items() it would return immutable tuples**

Output

```
[(1, {'age': 16, 'name': 'John', 'height': 173}), (3, {'age': 17, 'name': 'Luke', 'height': 181}), (2, {'age': 18, 'name
': 'Fred', 'height': 185})]
```

Comment: OP wants to sort by `'age'` not by the keys.

Comment: It automatically arrange it by age. Try to run the program in your own comp